# save sherlockfragment view when switching between tabs ( buttons and textviews )

Tags: tabs, android-fragments, view, actionbarsherlock

I added Tabs in my app using SherlockFragments but I don't know how to save the views. One of the Fragments has buttons and textviews and when I switch back and forth between tabs, the buttons are set to their initial state. I read about onSaveInstanceState() method but so far I am still not able to make it work.

Comment: excuse me sir , i know its been a long time , but how did you figure out ,how to deal with this issue.Can you please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found an answer and hope this might help someone, you can just adjust the Viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
(Depending how many screens you want to retain) . 
But do not put a large number,because it effects the performance tremendously.